# Board and lodging vs boarding and lodging

Tags: phrases

> He paid the caretaker for his board and lodging.

Or

> He paid the caretaker for his boarding and lodging.

Which one is correct?

Comment: ***room and board*** is the typical colocation.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

*Board and lodging* is correct. Oxforddictionaries.com even gives this phrase as an example: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/board.

*He* paid the caretaker for the provision of regular meals, which is board (not boarding).

Comment: I believe that 'board' in this context is an old word for 'table', so the traditional phrase 'board and lodging' means 'meals and sleeping accommodation'.